# bottom scroll is not working in table view

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I am having a table view. in that I am displaying an array. when I scroll the tableview its not moving up to the bottom of a last table cell. what should I do for that.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {  

return tableResourceArray.count;}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

       NSString *cellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomCell:%d",indexPath.row];

customcell *cell = (customcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[customcell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}
   if(tableView==table) {  
            table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            table.separatorColor=[UIColor clearColor];


    NSDictionary *slug = [category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"gggg:%@",slug);
            cell.ctitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [slug objectForKey:@"title"]];
            cell.ctitle.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12];

            cell.cdate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date:%@", [slug objectForKey:@"date"]];
            cell.cdate.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.820 green:0.776 blue:0.526 alpha:1.000];
            cell.ccontent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [slug objectForKey:@"content"]];
```

}

Comment: What is tablview frame? parent of tableview code too..

Comment: table.frame=CGRectMake(0, 130, 320, 480); this is my table view frame

Comment: are you using UINavigationCongroller?

Comment: yes i am using uinavigationcontroller in all pages

Comment: make sure in your ViewWillApear method set below properties  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO; and set your tableview frame as below table.frame=CGRectMake(0, 130, 320, 480-navigationbarHeight-statusbarHeight);

Comment: bro its not working bro

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? The table is not scrolling, or the cell is not being created? Have you tried logging some value (like `indexPath.row` or `[slug objectForKey:@"title"]`)in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to check if it is being called for the last cell ? Also, it seems you do not want to reuse any cells. A different `cellIdentifier` for each row means no reusing. A new instance will be created for each `cellIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

You have declared Identifier as **non-static variable**. This might cause scroll issue.

```
NSString *cellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomCell:%d",indexPath.row];
```

Instead use below :

```
NSString *cellIdentifier= @"CustomCellIdentifier";
```

Static variable are used to **construct only once and it avoid memory creation** all the time whenever “CellForRowAtIndexPath” method is called. If non-static variable is used lots of memory are created that may lead to scrolling issue.

**Solution 2 :** // Not sure. But might help

Allocate dictionary before usage.

```
    NSDictionary *slug = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    slug = [category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing my table view frame.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your screen size is 320x480, the bottom part of your table view frame is out of screen by 130 because of your table view's frame (origin y 130 + height 480). Or even more off if you have more subviews at the bottom of screen that cover tableview. Change your table view frame so that the bottom of your table view ends at the bottom of the screen.